# Layout not comming correct. bottom text box is hiding and toolbar not coming

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a music player and I am using ringtone cutter. I got ref from [ringdroid](https://github.com/google/ringdroid) on Github. But when I include a layout in my solution it doesn't work correctly. The Toolbar is not visible and text box if coming half. [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r91wR.png).. what should look like and what is coming.
Below is layout which issue.

[And here is the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MTbM.png)

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!-- ImageView android:id="@+id/bkgnd"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
         android:src="@drawable/bkgnd" -->

        <com.kpgames.shravanmusicplayer.ringtonecutter.WaveformView android:id="@+id/waveform"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <com.kpgames.shravanmusicplayer.ringtonecutter.MarkerView android:id="@+id/startmarker"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/endmarker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/marker_left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/start_marker" />

        <com.kpgames.shravanmusicplayer.ringtonecutter.MarkerView android:id="@+id/endmarker"
            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/startmarker"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/marker_right"
            android:contentDescription="@string/end_marker" />

    </AbsoluteLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/info"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/endmarker"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/AudioFileInfoOverlayText"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/ToolbarBackground"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dip"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/rew"
            android:layout_width="64dip"
            android:layout_height="52dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
            style="@android:style/MediaButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/rewind"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="71dip"
            android:layout_height="52dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
            style="@android:style/MediaButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/play"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ffwd"
            android:layout_width="64dip"
            android:layout_height="52dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
            style="@android:style/MediaButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ffwd"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout style="@style/HorizontalDividerTop" />
    <LinearLayout style="@style/HorizontalDividerBottom" />

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/ToolbarBackground"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mark_start"
                android:text="@string/start_label"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="31dip" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/starttext"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
                android:layout_width="70dip"
                android:layout_height="31dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/start_label" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mark_end"
                android:text="@string/end_label"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="31dip" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/endtext"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                android:layout_width="70dip"
                android:layout_height="31dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/end_label" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **both** `EditText - start_label and end_label` height from `31dp` to as per your `View` size(assumed `45dp` here)to:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/endtext"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="45dip"  //<---here
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription="@string/end_label" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `AbsoluteLayout`, it is deprecated. Try `RelativeLayout` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight=".8">

        <com.kpgames.shravanmusicplayer.ringtonecutter.WaveformView
            android:id="@+id/waveform"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <com.kpgames.shravanmusicplayer.ringtonecutter.MarkerView
            android:id="@+id/startmarker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/start_marker"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/endmarker"
            android:src="@drawable/marker_left" />

        <com.kpgames.shravanmusicplayer.ringtonecutter.MarkerView
            android:id="@+id/endmarker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/end_marker"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/info"
            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/startmarker"
            android:src="@drawable/marker_right" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/play"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/endmarker" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dip"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/rew"
            style="@android:style/MediaButton"
            android:layout_width="64dip"
            android:layout_height="52dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:contentDescription="rewind"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/play"
            style="@android:style/MediaButton"
            android:layout_width="71dip"
            android:layout_height="52dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:contentDescription="play"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ffwd"
            style="@android:style/MediaButton"
            android:layout_width="64dip"
            android:layout_height="52dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:contentDescription="ffwd"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mark_start"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="31dip"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="start label"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/starttext"
                android:layout_width="70dip"
                android:layout_height="31dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
                android:contentDescription="start label"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mark_end"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="31dip"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="end lable"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/endtext"
                android:layout_width="70dip"
                android:layout_height="31dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:contentDescription="end label"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```